# Copiar texto de una imagen

Tags: android-studio

llevo dandole vueltas un tiempo y me gustaria saber si se podria extraer un texto de una imagen sin extraerlo manualmente para luego traducirlo a cualquier idioma en una aplicacion Android que quiero hacer. Me explico, cojo una foto, ya sea de camara o de galeria, y que al hacerlo, me gustaria que, o bien te permita seleccionar el texto de esa imagen como si ya  estuviese extraido, es decir, manteniendo pulsado el texto de la imagen y vas seleccionando la cantidad de texto que deseas obtener para posteriormente pasar a traducirlo, o bien que la propia aplicacion detecte el idioma que reconozca en la imagen y me lleve a la sección de traducir a otro idioma.
Es básicamente como hace Google Lens, hace una foto y permite seleccionar el texto de esa foto sin haberle hecho un OCR antes, es decir, que no habia ningun boton que permitiese extraer el texto primero para luego seleccionarlo, directamente lo hacia la aplicacion y listo.
Por eso me gustaria saber si saben de alguna herramienta que haga eso en Android studio, alguna dependencia que pueda servir para implementarla a la nueva aplicacion que me gustaria hacer. Resultaria comodo para el usuario que reconociese el texto sin necesidad de que el propio usuario primero pulse en el boton de extraer texto y luego pasar a traducirlo.

Cualquier sugerencia estare agradecido. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa por favor [ask] modifica tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada, saludos.